# Django form is not valid, when I trying to update Image

Tags: python, django, forms, image, validation

I use this form for adding and updating posts. When I want to edit post and update image Django adds ['image-clear'] checkbox if post has image. But it doesn`t work. Form is not valid, if I tick checkbox and choose new image.But if I only choose new image (without tick checkbox) it works.

I was looking for a long time in what the problem, but I did not find. Can you help me? And sorry for my English

forms.py

```
class AddIdeaFrom(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Idea
    fields = ['title', 'description', 'image']
title = forms.CharField(max_length=500, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
description = forms.CharField(max_length=500, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
image = forms.FileField(required=False)
```

views.py

```
def idea_edit(request,idea_id):

if request.method == "GET":
    idea = Idea.objects.get(id=idea_id)
    edit_idea = AddIdeaFrom(initial={'title':idea.title,'description':idea.description,'image':idea.image})
    return render(request, 'myidea/my/idea_edit.html', {'form':edit_idea, 'comment':idea.comment})

if request.method == "POST":
    idea = Idea.objects.get(id=idea_id)
    edit_idea = AddIdeaFrom(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if edit_idea.is_valid(): 
        edit_idea = AddIdeaFrom(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=idea)
        if edit_idea.has_changed():
            new_idea = edit_idea.save()
            new_status = Status.objects.get(name = STATUS_REVIEW)
            new_idea.status = new_status
            new_idea.save()
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Need some changes')
    else:
        form = AddIdeaFrom(instance= idea)
        return render(request, 'myidea/my/idea_edit.html', {'form': form})
```

html

```
<form method="post" class="post-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <label for="description.for_label" class="col-sm-9">Text</label>
            {{ form.description }}

        <label for="description.for_image" class="col-sm-9">Choose Image</label>
        {{ form.image }}

        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-space mb-">Add</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: can you edit post with errors from validation? Try something like this: print(edit_idea.errors)

Comment: I try to use {{form.errors}} in my template, but nothing happens

Comment: Oh... It works: "Please upload the file or check the box "Clear", but do not do both at the same time." Now everything is clear, thank you

Comment: So it look you have choosed imaged and simultaneously selected clear checkbox. You can check all values in form via print(edit_idea). Check it in console of development server. It is much easier. You should see there all inputs with values from your form. You can post it here if you want

Answer (score 0):

From your comment it looks you have problem with contradictory data in your form. It is probably because of using "Clear" checkbox with `FileField` widget. Try this in your `forms.py`:

```
image = forms.FileField(widget=FileInput, required=False)
```

This should remove "Clear" checkbox from your form.
Or if you don't want let user clear image you can unselect it in view before validation.